Prepopulating v-date-picker programatically with validation
I have a v-data-picker that the selected value will fill in a v-text-field and display a cleaner formatted date that was chosen. The issue is I sometimes pre-populate this date from other aspects of my application. This is working great but when doing this programmatically the validation rule I have setup is not triggering the validation. If I manually select the date the validation triggers and if its valid my form can move to next step. My form is as follows:
            <v-form v-model="additionalDetailsValid" @submit.prevent>
              <v-card
                flat
                class="pt-5"
              >
                <v-menu v-model="stateSubmissionDateMenu"
                      :close-on-content-click="false"
                      transition="scale-transition"
                      offset-y
                      max-width="290px"
                      min-width="auto">
                  <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
                    <v-text-field
                      color="primary"
                      v-bind="props"
                      label="State Submission Date"
                      :model-value="formatDate(stateSubmissionDateModel,'MM/DD/YYYY')?.toString()"
                      prepend-inner-icon="mdi-calendar"
                      :rules="objectRequiredRule"
                      validate-on="lazy input"
                      readonly
                      variant="outlined"/>
                  </template>
                  <v-date-picker 
                    v-model="stateSubmissionDateModel"
                    color="primary"
                    no-title
                    :max="new Date()"
                    @update:modelValue="stateSubmissionDateMenu = false"></v-date-picker>
                </v-menu>    
              </v-card>
            </v-form>

My code which programmaticaly sets it is as follows:
      const getEmailImportData = () => {
    //state submission date
    if(newReviewEmailData.value?.receive_date) {
      stateSubmissionDateModel.value = dayjs(newReviewEmailData.value?.receive_date).toDate()
    }   
  }


Since you only want to validate a single text field:
Online demo playground
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-text-field label="Label" :rules="requiredRules"></v-text-field>
      <v-text-field :rules="requiredRules" ref="sampleField"></v-text-field>
      <v-btn @click="submit">submit</v-btn>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>
<script setup>
  import { computed, onMounted } from 'vue'
  import { ref } from 'vue'

  let sampleField = ref(null)

  const requiredRules = computed(() => {
    return [v => !!v || 'This field is required']
  })
  const submit = () => {
    sampleField.value.validate()
  }
</script>


The issue is this would trigger all the other fields in the form. I have some other inputs I removed from this example for brevity. But there are other fields which the user will get to and if all the validation is triggered before it even shows up then the user experience my be hurt a bit. Can I target that exact field for validation instead?

Have you tried to validate the single field? this.$refs.textfield.validate()
I have commented in the code snippet

Is text field a predetermined name or should that be the v-model of the v-text-field?

@Qiuzman you should have a ref in the template: ref="textfield"

Could you do the full example in your answer for this solution? I don’t think I’m understanding exactly because th v-text-field shouldn’t have a template.

@Qiuzman sure, please find the the full code sample in updated answer.

@Qiuzman does it solve your problem?

I will be back to work in a few days and will test it and and report back. Looks like it should tho!
